# How can I troubleshoot why Bootstrap 4's sticky-top class does not work on my page?

Tags: css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I know that there are several sticky-top questions out there but I haven't found a solution yet. Here is my code:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="container">

    <header class="header-container text-center">

        <div class="social-menu" style="height: 20%">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"> </i> <i class="fa fa-instagram"> </i> <i class="fa fa-twitter-square"> </i> <i class="fa fa-youtube-square"></i></h3>
        </div>

        <div class="header-content table" style="height: 60%">
            <div class="table-cell">
                <div class="logo-image"></div>
                <h1 class="site-title"><span class="d-none"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></span></h1>
                <!-- add hidden title for SEO -->
                <h2>Španski Metar</h2>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav-container">
            <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg is-sticky navbar-light navbar-spanski">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="<?php esc_html_e( 'Toggle Navigation', 'spanski_metar' ); ?>">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-center" id="navbar-content">
                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu([
                    'menu'            => 'main_menu',
                    'theme_location'  => 'main_menu',
                    'menu_id'         => false,
                    'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                    'depth'           => 2,
                    'fallback_cb'     => 'nav_walker::fallback',
                    'walker'          => new nav_walker()
                    ]);
                    ?>
                    <!-- <div id="navsearch">
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                        <input class="form-control-sm" style="padding-left:5px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;" type="search" placeholder="Pretraga" aria-label="Search">
                        <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </form>
                    </div> -->
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div style="height: 1000px"></div>
        </div><!-- .nav-container -->

    </header>   

</div>
```

The only way I've found sticky-top to work is if I put the 1000px height div inside the nav-container div. But that's not what I want to do. Is there no way to keep the navbar sticky-top and also inside the header? Isn't that the best practice?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Where do you want the header? Do you want the Navbar after the header, or after the 1000px div. The question isn't clear.

Comment: Inside the header tag I want to have first the social media menu, then a logo image, then the navbar. I added the tall div just so I could test sticky-top.

Comment: How to be sticky if there is no content? It has the class sticky but you can't see it if the content of the page is not larger than the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

Check your jquery and "bootstrap.min.js" file. They are not Uploaded correctly

Use the scripts on the bottom of the page and use them on correct position, First use jquery and then bootstrap

like:

-- Jquery --

-- Bootstrap --

Comment: I'm enqueueing them in Wordpress in this order:

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js');